# Regex Javascript Numbers Comma Separated | > | >= <=

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm using this Regex to validate numbers with decimals (comma separated)

```
/(^\d*\,?\d*[1-9]+\d*$)|(^[1-9]+\d*\,\d*$)/
```

but i need to change it so that it can also validate numbers higher than 5000 and between 3000 and 1000000

I'm not a Regex expert even though i have read several tutorials i'm still unable to find a solution...any help is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "*higher than 5000 and between 3000 and 1000000*"? Are you looking for 2 different patterns or one pattern that validates numbers between 5000 and 1000000?

Comment: 2 patterns. between 5000-any_number and 3000-1000000 (allowing decimals with comma)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will match numbers between 3000 and 1000000, inclusive, allowing an optional fractional part separated by a coma:

```
 /^([3-9][0-9]{3}(,[0-9]+)?|[1-9][0-9]{4,5}(,[0-9]+)?|1000000)$/
```

You can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%28%5B3-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%28%2C%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F%7C%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B4%2C5%7D%28%2C%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F%7C1000000%29%29%24&input=2000%0A3000%0A5000%2C001%0A10000%0A100000%0A1000000%0A10000000).

This will match numbers greater or equal to 5000, allowing an optional fractional part separated by a coma:

```
 /^([5-9][0-9]{3}|[1-9][0-9]{4,})(,[0-9]+)?$/
```

You can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%5B5-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%7C%5B1-9%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B4%2C%7D%29%28%2C%5B0-9%5D%2B%29%3F%24&input=2000%0A3000%0A5000%2C001%0A10000%0A100000%0A1000000%0A10000000).

Comment: witchcraft! genius, thank you so much! if you're able to provide me any app/tutorial that can help me to solve regex problems in the future, that would be very useful to me. thanks!

Comment: @Carlos [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) is an excellent resource. [regexper.com](http://www.regexper.com/) is also a great tool for dissecting regular expressions.